# How to select input::placeholder using JS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have this CSS: `input::placeholder {font-size: 30px}`

and I trying to change input placeholder CSS in JS

```
var inputPlaceholder = document.querySelector("input::placeholder");
inputPlaceholder.style.fontSize = "5px";
```

but console returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

How to to change input placeholder CSS in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Try For This:

```
<input type="text" style="font-size: 30px" placeholder="Here." id="new"/>

var inputPlaceholder = document.getElementById('new');
inputPlaceholder.style.fontSize = "5px";
```